# Paypal not accepting parallel payments through form

Tags: forms, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

Paypal gives me an error message when I pass an email as a recipient of payment through a post variable in my form.

```
"We cannot process this transaction because there is a problem with the PayPal email address supplied by the seller. Please contact the seller to resolve the problem."
```

I am using this code:

```
<form  id="sub" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="visibility: hidden">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="receiverList.receiver(0).email"="trecoolable@gmail.com"> //part that needs to work for parallel paymentsvalue
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="CA">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Tangled Roots">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="cn" value="Add special instructions to the seller">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
<input name="receiverList.receiver(0).amount" value="16.99">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="CAD">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                </form>
```

How do I pass multiple recipients and not get an error through PayPal?

Comment: code taken from a sample, working fine when business is put in place of `receiverList.receiver(0).email` Just need to have two recipients

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Parallel Payments you have to use either the [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) API or the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) API, specifically [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/?mark=Pay).

Comment: Would that mean I cannot pass the information from a custom form?

Comment: You can integrate APIs in any way you see fit, so a custom form would not be a problem at all.  You just can't do it with a PayPal Standard form like you're attempting here.  You need to build your own form that generates an API request.

Comment: How would that be formatted? Because I've been researching adaptive api and it does not cover using forms. Where could I find a sample or example of a form that I should be structuring by?

Comment: You would build your own form and have that form POST to your own page that generates the API request using data passed through the form.